# Finding if a character is a capital in a string (python)

Tags: python

The code that I have so far is:

```
password = input("Please enter a password: ")
letter = len(password)
if letters <= 5:
print ("WEAK")
elif
```

I know the answer is probably really obvious but I just can't see it - what i need it to be able to see whether the letters are capitals. There is other stuff that I need aswell but I'm working through it one step at a time. Please help?

Comment: `if 'A' <= c <= 'Z'` where `c` is the character you're checking

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i check if a letter in a string is capitalized using python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697535/how-can-i-check-if-a-letter-in-a-string-is-capitalized-using-python)

Comment: Do you want to know whether any, or whether all characters in the string are capitals? In either case, how should non-alpha characters and characters from scripts without upper/lower distinction be treated?

Answer (score 3):

String has *isupper* function:

Use it as follow:

```
 >>> 'e'.isupper()
 False
 >>> 'E'.isupper()
 True
 >>> 'Ennn'.isupper()
 False
 >>> 'EEE'.isupper()
 >>> 'eee'.isupper()
 False
 >>> 'EEEEe'.isupper()
 False
```

If you want to check if *at lest one* char is upper, you can use *any*

```
 >>> any([x.isupper() for x in list('eeeeE')])
 True
 >>> any([x.isupper() for x in list('eeee')])
 False
 >>> any([x.isupper() for x in list('EEEE')])
 True
```

Docs:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any

Comment: You're quite in love with lists, it seems. `any(x.isupper() for x in 'eeeeE')` works as well (if not better).